# Does directory made inside writable directory always writable?

Tags: php, writable

I have a directory that is writable.If i make another directory inside it using

```
mkdir("test", 0777);
```

Does this make test directory writable ?

if i use only

```
mkdir("test");
```

does it inherit the writable property from its parent dir?

If not is there a way to make it inherit. So that i do not have to individually make it writable?

Comment: You are explicitly specifiying a chmod, there's nothing about inheritance here

Comment: you have to explicilty give write premission to directory

Comment: @RoyalBg was editing the question :)

Comment: @Ace so, no :) It will not inherit :) You will have a non-writable directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your both supposed options are not true. Result permissions will not be neither *exact* `777` nor "inherited" from parent directory.

To understand what will happen, you need to understand two points:

- What is **umask**. In *nix systems it's a special mask that is applied to newly created file system elements (directories or files. Well, actually, directory is a file too, but that's out of issue). You can work with it in PHP via [`umask()`](https://www.php.net/mkdir)
- For [`mkdir()`](https://www.php.net/mkdir) second parameter is not just "exact permissions". **umask** will modify it. So end result may (and, best chances are - will be) differ from `777`.

Also there's important to realize - that Windows permissions systems is different from *nix - you can not rely on described above when working under Win systems.

Comment: If i use umask() will it work on *nix & windows both?

Comment: No, umask is a *nix-specific thing. It has nothing to do with Windows, so you'll not get expected result with Win systems

Comment: You need to define what is "work" for Windows then - because *nix permission system is not applicable under Windows at all - it has own system, much more complicated

Comment: i'm creating directories and making it writable

Comment: Even in *nix "writable"  isn't enough to define permissions (because it's about owner-writable/group writable/all writable). And in Win this situation is more complex. So - writable to who?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43917/discussion-between-ace-and-alma-do)

Comment: writable to all,
directories will hold user uploads

Answer (score 1):

No, directories nor files do not inherit attributes from parent element. But `test` will be world writable because you explicitly set it so with `0777`. We have 3 octal digits these digits represent the rights of, in order, owner, group and world to the resource. since 8 is the 3rd power of 2 we can represent 3 states with each octal digit (since 4+2+1=7) depending on which values are set (this is a bitmask i.e. based on powers of 2, handy to manipulate with bitwise operations)

```
1 = executable
2 = writable
4 = readable
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of mkdir is the access mask for the new directory.

```
mkdir( 'test', 0777 );
```

Would create the directory test at your current location (`getcwd()`) and make it writeable for everyone.

Access rights are not inherited, they are set separately for each file and directory